# Flask, 404 errors when serving static file with send_from_directory

Tags: flask

```
@app.route('/Images/<path:filename>')
@login_required
def sstatic(filename):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(root_dir,'ca','static', 'Images'), filename)

@app.route('/stest')
@login_required
def stest():
    return redirect(url_for('sstatic',filename='a.png'))
```

Upon using /stest, I expect to be redirected to the static image 'a.png'. However I keep getting a 404 error. The png file exists in my > static > Images. The`os.path.join(root_dir,'ca','static', 'Images')` is the correct location. Flask simply isn't sending the file.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: i guess you don't need `path` in `@app.route('/Images/<path:filename>')` just pass the `filename` as string like `@app.route('/Images/filename')`

Comment: TypeError: sstatic() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

Comment: my bad, i missed `<`  and `>` in `@app.route('/Images/filename')`, the right way is this : `@app.route('/Images/<filename>')`, i'm sorry

Comment: It doesn't crash, but sadly hasn't solved the problem. "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."